# Adding a custom class to the element on which is clicked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

New to Angular so I cant seem to get it to work but I have a list of element which has the option that if somebody click on the element it show toggls between show/hide (toggle a class). My code works but it will toggle ALL elements at once instead of the one that has been clicked on. Looked for some examples online but found almost the same stuff.

```
// class
public toggleClass = false;
public onToggleDiv(): void {
    this.toggleClass = !this.toggleClass;
}

// component
<div
    class="group"
    (click)="onToggleDiv()"
    [ngClass]="{'active' : toggleClass}"
>
    Some content
</div>

<div
    class="group"
    (click)="onToggleDiv()"
    [ngClass]="{'active' : toggleClass}"
>
    Some content
</div>

... and more divs
```

**Solution for now**
(only 1 box can be open sadly)

```
// class
public toggleRow: boolean | number = false;
public onToggleDiv(): void {
    this.toggleRow = this.toggleRow === id ? false : id;
}

// component
<div
    class="group"
    (click)="onToggleDiv(1)"
    [class.active]="toggleClass === 1"
>
    Some content
</div>

<div
    class="group"
    (click)="onToggleDiv(2)"
    [class.active]="toggleClass === 2"
>
    Some content
</div>

... and more divs
```

Comment: Each of those divs looks very similar. Consider making a separate component that encapsulates the concept of that toggle. Then your current typescript code would work (because `this.toggleClass` would refer to that specific instance). Your higher-level component would just declare several instances of those subcomponents.

Answer (score 1):

You should work with an array of numbers to define which item should have the class or not. I assumed you were in a loop or have any kind of identifier for your div. Here is [a example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dz16cq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) about how you can do something similar and here is the code:

ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  items = Array.from(Array(10).keys());
  toggledItems: number[] = [];

  toggleItem = (i: number) => {
    if (this.toggledItems.includes(i)) {
      this.toggledItems = this.toggledItems.filter((x) => x !== i);
    } else {
      this.toggledItems.push(i);
    }
  };
}
```

html:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <div [ngClass]="{ hidden: toggledItems.includes(i) }">
    Element <button type="button" (click)="toggleItem(i)">Hide me</button>
  </div>
</div>>
</div>
```

css:

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0.3
}
```

Comment: This will not work, as it will only allow 1 element open/closed at the time

Comment: @user759235 Of course it does, you just need to manage an array instead of just a single number. I edited my answer for this.

Comment: in Quentien's defence, I also understood that you were looking for only one to be opened at a time "ALL elements at once instead of the one that has been clicked on"

Answer (score 0):

In your component

```js
// class
public toggleClass = false;
public currentActive = 0;
public onToggleDiv(id): void {
    this.toggleClass = !this.toggleClass;
    currentActive = this.toggleClass ? id : 0;
}
```

In your template:

```html
// component
<div class="group"
     (click)="onToggleDiv(1)"
     [class.active]="currentActive == 1">
    Some content
</div>

<div class="group"
     (click)="onToggleDiv(2)"
     [class.active]="currentActive == 2">
    Some content
</div>
```

References:

- [Angular attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding)
- [Extendend guide](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/),
- [Angular docs to ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass),

Comment: This will add the class active to ALL div's

Comment: You're right, I changed my answer

Comment: The toggleClass variable is redundant in your example as this does nothing. I have used your idea and added a solution in my answer, but this approach creates a new issue, it only works for the selected div, if you click on a other div it will remove the state/class from the other clicked elements.